# How can I use CORS with tomcat6?

Tags: tomcat6, cors

How do I install and enable CORS for Tomcat 6?  There is lots of documentation out there for Tomcat 7 or later, and lots assuming you already have the CORS filter jar file, but none that start with telling you where to download jar for Tomcat 6.  For instance, I can find some directions [here](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html), but that assumes I am using JavaServlet 3.0 or later container.  I am pretty sure Tomcat 6 uses a prior JavaServlet specification, and I don't know which CORS filter supports this earlier version of JavaServlet.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: See https://www.dforge.net/2013/09/16/enabling-cors-on-apache-tomcat-6/

Comment: I did, but it does not tell me which jar file to download.  Regardless, I sort of guessed which one to download and it partially works.